# Laravel - Eloquent: API Resources - Conditional Relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I think I might have found a bug in Laravel, please see the below code:

I am hitting an endpoint which is `/api/users/1`

```
public function show(User $user)
{
    return new UserResource($user);
}
```

My Resource looks like the below:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class LenderTrancheCommitment extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {

        //dd($this);

        return [
            'uuid'               => $this->uuid,
            'name'               => $this->name,
            'currency'           => $this->currency,
            'company'            => new CompanyResource($this->whenLoaded('company')),
            'created_at'         => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at'         => $this->updated_at,
        ];
    }
}
```

Now I would expect the company property not to return in the JSON however it does, can anyone see a reason why the company relation is being loaded and added to the JSON response when I am not using `->with()` anywhere in my code?

Sorry if this is a total n00b mistake but I want to properly understand the new API resource stuff in Laravel and I feel like I am making a mistake.

Comment: do you have a $with property in model ? try User::setEagerLoads([]) to be sure

Comment: also try it like this CompanyResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('company'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this, the issue is due to having an attribute in the model that used property from a relation.